# Recognising hash/checksum

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, reverse-engineering, checksum

**Hello everyone,**

In one of projects I've found that data encrypts with algorithm I have never meet before. It converts input string to 10-symbol numeric string. It's definitely not one of popular hashes (md5, sha1, etc) or check sums (crc16, crc32, etc), I've checked all I known.

**Example:**
Input string: "*davidc*"; Output string: "*2172453193*".

Length of output string is fixed - 10 symbols. It contains only digits ("*0123456789*"). This is all details i can add =/

Maybe someone met something similar to that or maybe know algorithm - You'll economy lot of my time.

With love <3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and.. what makes you think it's not a hash or checksum? it's only matter of representation. e.g. number you've provided can be represented as 32 bit array ( `817d0149` in hex). Though without any more details you have no means to know (and definitelly we have no idea where you took it from)

Comment: You need to provide us with at least 10 examples of input amd output strings.